# Words seem to be missing in "Share a link to this question..." message

Tags: bug

Right above the Answer box, we have the *Share a link to this question* message. This is how I see it:

[image: too many commas]

I'm using Firefox Quantom with uBlock.

Comment: It's supposed to be “via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.” and that's exactly how I see it with Vivaldi, uBlock Plus and Ghostery. Did you try disabling uBlock (just for testing of course)? Do you have any userscripts (Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey) enabled that could case the issue? Or anything else that blocks social network stuff?

Comment: @dessert I do see the whole sentence after disabling uBlock..weird though because I don't have that problem on SO.

Comment: I don't have this problem with Adblock, but it might be because uBlock blocks social links by default but it has whitelisted [SO] and not Ask Ubuntu. Does the same issue occur on [SU] or [SF]?

Comment: Yes and it seems like it's happening on SO now..